# How do I shift all of the elements of an array from the left side to the right side in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I am trying to swap the elements of an array from the far left all the way to the far right.

So the array looks like this: 1234567

And I want the output to be like this: 7654321

I have tried this but all it does is move only the last digit on the left side to the right side and no other digits.

```
    static int[] ShiftArray(int[] array)
    {
        int[] temp = new int[array.Length];
        for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
        {
            temp[(index + 1) % temp.Length] = array[index];
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I would describe this as reversing an array, not shifting an array (shifting is a completely different operation entirely).

Comment: A hint: You want to reverse direction, it means you have to read from left and write to right, or read form right and write to left. So you need to move one of pointers from right to left, i.e. subtract by one on each step. temp.Length - 1 - index...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use any pre-built .NET functions, you can try the following:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        int start = 0;
        int end = array.Length - 1;
        while (start < end)
        {
            int temp = array[start];
            array[start] = array[end];
            array[end] = temp;
            start++;
            end--;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", String.Join("", array));
    }
}
```

Whenever you swap elements in an array, you need a temp variable to hold an element while the swap is being performed.

The `start` and `end` variables are to track where you're at in the array.  Once they cross each other, you're done swapping elements around.

**RESULT**

```
Result: 7654321
```

**DEMO**

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nkaMXg)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the order in the array itself (without creating a new array), you can use the following:

```
Array.Reverse(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `Reverse` from `System.Linq`.

```
return array.ToList().Reverse().ToArray();
```

Comment: The call to `ToList()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just iterate through the array in decreasing order?

```
for(int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    // do something
}
```